# How do I get my api call to call a different file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using the api http://aws.random.cat/meow and it gives me a result of

```
{"file": "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/rEJ7q.jpg"}
```

The file changes every time I refresh the api call on the browser which gives me a different cat pic. For example, if I refresh it would give me a different .jpg like

```
{"file": "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/ferbus.jpg"}
```

I call the api in my React app, and I want to randomize the cat pic after an onClick of a button. Unfortunately, I get the same picture back when I do my api call. I put the file in an img src, but it doesn't change when I do another api call.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCats();
  }

  getCats = () => {
    axios.get(`http://aws.random.cat/meow`)
      .then(res => {
        let cats = res.data.file;
        console.log(cats)
        this.setState({
          cats
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <img
            src={this.state.cats}
            alt='cat'
          />
        <button onClick={this.getCats}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I expect to get a different file every time, but instead I get the same .jpg when I do an onClick.

Comment: what does the console.log show after the request? Does it show different links?

Comment: The console.log shows the same file. I realized that this isn't working when I put my axios call in a different file. It started giving me different pictures when I put everything back in the app.js. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: One reason from the top of my head maybe because the browser is caching the data. Open the chrome devtools and go to the network tab. Go to resources and check there. You get request result might be having a status code of 304 and should say from disk cache. If not then I don't know what is happening there

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working. I forgot to call the function after I imported it. Thank you!